# How can I explicitly declare a view from a Rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to explicitly call a view from my controller.

Right now I have:

```
def some_action
  .. do something ...
  respond_to do |format|
    format.xml
  end
end
```

... then it calls my some_action.xml.builder view.  How can I call some other view?  Is there a parameter in respond_to I'm missing?

Thanks,

JP

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You could do something like the following using render:

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render :template => "weblog/show" }
end
```

Answer (score 15):

See the [Rendering section of the ActionController::Base documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html#M000474) for the different ways you can control what to render.

You can tell Rails to render a specific view (template) like this:

```
# Renders the template located in [TEMPLATE_ROOT]/weblog/show.r(html|xml) (in Rails, app/views/weblog/show.erb)
  render :template => "weblog/show"

# Renders the template with a local variable
  render :template => "weblog/show", :locals => {:customer => Customer.new}
```

Answer (score 9):

Or even simpler since [Rails > 3.0](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-an-action-s-view):

```
render "edit"
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also pass :action, or :controller if that's more convenient.

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render :action => 'show' }
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the internal `lookup_context` of the controller by doing this in your controller

```
before_filter do
  lookup_context.prefixes << 'view_prefix'
end
```

and the controller will try to load `view/view_prefix/show.html` when responding to an `show` request after looking for all the other view prefixes in the list. The default list is typically `application` and the name of the current controller.

```
class MagicController
  before_filter do
    lookup_context.prefixes << 'secondary'
  end

  def show
    # ...
  end
end

app.get '/magic/1`
```

This `GET` request will look for a view in the following order:

- `view/application/show.erb`
- `view/magic/show.erb`
- `view/secondary/show.erb`

and use the first found view.

Answer (score 0):

Use render

http://api.rubyonrails.com/classes/ActionController/Base.html#M000474